# Matplotlib imshow/matshow display values on plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, visualization

I am trying to create a 10x10 grid using either `imshow` or `matshow` in Matplotlib. The function below takes a numpy array as input, and plots the grid. However, I'd like to have values from the array also displayed inside the cells defined by the grid. So far I could not find a proper way to do it. I can use `plt.text` to place things over the grid, but this requires coordinates of each cell, totally inconvenient. Is there a better way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Thanks!

NOTE: The code below does not take the values from the array yet, I was just playing with `plt.text`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

board = np.zeros((10, 10))

def visBoard(board):
   cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['white', 'red'])
   bounds=[0,0.5,1]
   norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
   plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
   plt.matshow(board, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, interpolation='none', vmin=0, vmax=1)
   plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5,10.5), [])
   plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5,10.5), [])
   plt.text(-0.1, 0.2, 'x')
   plt.text(0.9, 0.2, 'o')
   plt.text(1.9, 0.2, 'x')
   plt.grid()

   visBoard(board)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: use annotate which lets you be very flexible with how you specify the coordinates of the text.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to do this without specifying the coordinates. So far, I did it manually (may not be the smartest idea) Assuming the figure size may change, I will have to come up with a function which calculates the correct coordinates.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Can you do something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

min_val, max_val = 0, 10
ind_array = np.arange(min_val + 0.5, max_val + 0.5, 1.0)
x, y = np.meshgrid(ind_array, ind_array)

for i, (x_val, y_val) in enumerate(zip(x.flatten(), y.flatten())):
    c = 'x' if i%2 else 'o' 
    ax.text(x_val, y_val, c, va='center', ha='center')
#alternatively, you could do something like
#for x_val, y_val in zip(x.flatten(), y.flatten()):
#    c = 'x' if (x_val + y_val)%2 else 'o'

ax.set_xlim(min_val, max_val)
ax.set_ylim(min_val, max_val)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(max_val))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(max_val))
ax.grid()
```

[image]

---

Edit:

Here is an updated example with an `imshow` background.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

min_val, max_val, diff = 0., 10., 1.

#imshow portion
N_points = (max_val - min_val) / diff
imshow_data = np.random.rand(N_points, N_points)
ax.imshow(imshow_data, interpolation='nearest')

#text portion
ind_array = np.arange(min_val, max_val, diff)
x, y = np.meshgrid(ind_array, ind_array)

for x_val, y_val in zip(x.flatten(), y.flatten()):
    c = 'x' if (x_val + y_val)%2 else 'o'
    ax.text(x_val, y_val, c, va='center', ha='center')

#set tick marks for grid
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(min_val-diff/2, max_val-diff/2))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(min_val-diff/2, max_val-diff/2))
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_xlim(min_val-diff/2, max_val-diff/2)
ax.set_ylim(min_val-diff/2, max_val-diff/2)
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will try to iterate on this. I have to use imshow/matshow plot as a base since it will display a heat map. I was planning to have the values on the heatmap. However, I guess I can overlay what you have on top of my imshow/matshow plot. Let's try...

Comment: Thanks for the code! Please note that the resulting image might be shown upside down. You can prevent that by swapping the two arguments of set_ylim: ax.set_ylim(bottom=max_val - diff / 2, top=min_val - diff / 2)

Comment: @dev-random, depending on the arguments you supply to [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow), then the plot may appear differently than you expect (because of defaults to represent images well which are different than the standards used to show data plots).  Here I'm using the defaults.  But if you find the plot is somewhat rotated/upside down, check out the `origin` keyword argument.  You may need to set it to `origin='lower'`.

Answer (score 2):

For your graph you should should try with `pyplot.table`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

board = np.zeros((10, 10))
board[0,0] = 1
board[0,1] = -1
board[0,2] = 1
def visBoard(board):
    data = np.empty(board.shape,dtype=np.str)
    data[:,:] = ' '
    data[board==1.0] = 'X'
    data[board==-1.0] = 'O'
    plt.axis('off')
    size = np.ones(board.shape[0])/board.shape[0]
    plt.table(cellText=data,loc='center',colWidths=size,cellLoc='center',bbox=[0,0,1,1])
    plt.show()

visBoard(board)
```

Comment: is there a way to overlay this table over the imshow/matshow plot? I have to keep that which will be used as a heatmap. I just need the 'x' 'o''s overlayed on top of it.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to do something like `plt.plot(range(10),range(10))` and I see the plot below the table, the table is just like another plot.

Answer (score 2):

Some elaboration on the code of @wflynny making it into a function that takes any matrix no matter what size and plots its values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = np.random.randint(low=1,high=30)
rows = np.random.randint(low=1,high=30)
X = np.random.rand(rows,cols)

def plotMat(X):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    #imshow portion
    ax.imshow(X, interpolation='nearest')
    #text portion
    diff = 1.
    min_val = 0.
    rows = X.shape[0]
    cols = X.shape[1]
    col_array = np.arange(min_val, cols, diff)
    row_array = np.arange(min_val, rows, diff)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(col_array, row_array)
    for col_val, row_val in zip(x.flatten(), y.flatten()):
        c = '+' if X[row_val.astype(int),col_val.astype(int)] < 0.5 else '-' 
        ax.text(col_val, row_val, c, va='center', ha='center')
    #set tick marks for grid
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(min_val-diff/2, cols-diff/2))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(min_val-diff/2, rows-diff/2))
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.set_xlim(min_val-diff/2, cols-diff/2)
    ax.set_ylim(min_val-diff/2, rows-diff/2)
    ax.grid()
    plt.show()

plotMat(X)
```