# Colorplot of 2D array with Text Labels

Tags: python

I would like to replicate something like this in Python. Anyone know if this is possible?

I'll have a 2D array as input and text lists of labels for rows and columns.

The 2D array values should be plotted in each cell, as below.

[image: Colorplot of 2d array with text labels]

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21712361/1634191) might be relevant to your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since no one has answered you, here is a good starting point:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

z = np.random.rand(10, 10) # generate random data
nx, ny = z.shape
indx, indy = np.arange(nx), np.arange(ny)
x, y = np.meshgrid(indx, indy)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(z.T, interpolation="nearest", cmap=cm.YlGn) # plot grid values

for xval, yval in zip(x.flatten(), y.flatten()):
    zval = z[xval, yval]
    t = "%.1f%%"%(zval * 100,) # format value with 1 decimal point
    c = 'w' if zval > 0.75 else 'k' # if dark-green, change text color to white
    ax.text(xval, yval, t, color=c, va='center', ha='center')

xlabels = 'abcdefghij'
ylabels = '0123456789'
ax.set_xticks(indx+0.5) # offset x/y ticks so gridlines run on border of boxes
ax.set_yticks(indy+0.5)
ax.grid(ls='-', lw=2)

# the tick labels, if you want them centered need to be adjusted in 
# this special way.
for a, ind, labels in zip((ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis), (indx, indy), 
                          (xlabels, ylabels)):
    a.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
    a.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(ind))
    a.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(labels))

ax.xaxis.tick_top()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. This is very similar to my answer. I'll leave them both up.

Comment: How can I make xlabels vertical in the result plot? I mean I want to rotate xlables 90 degrees and then put them on x axis.

Comment: @K47 Something like `ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=90)`?

Comment: How to set the width of the border between cells?

Comment: @K47 Change the `lw` (linewidth) parameter of the call to `ax.grid(ls='-', lw=2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Bill, here is the answer, gently modified from his link

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))

min_val, max_val, diff = 0., 10., 1.

#imshow portion
N_points = (max_val - min_val) / diff

random.seed(42)
imshow_data = np.random.rand(N_points, N_points)
ax.imshow(imshow_data, interpolation='nearest', cmap="GnBu" )

#text portion
ind_array = np.arange(min_val, max_val, diff)
x, y = np.meshgrid(ind_array, ind_array)

# Write the text to correct positions
for x_val, y_val in zip(x.flatten(), y.flatten()):
    c = "{0:.2}".format(imshow_data[y_val, x_val])
    ax.text(x_val, y_val, c, va='center', ha='center')


#set tick marks for grid
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(min_val-diff/2, max_val-diff/2))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(min_val-diff/2, max_val-diff/2))

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(max_val))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(max_val))

ax.set_xlim(min_val-diff/2, max_val-diff/2)
ax.set_ylim(min_val-diff/2, max_val-diff/2)

ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]