# plot heatmap colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, colorbar

I am working on a plot which looks like this so far:

[image]

And I am using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
column_labels = ['A','B']
row_labels = ['A','B']
data = np.random.rand(2,2)
print(type(data))
data = np.array([[1, 0.232], [0.119, 1]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

# put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[0])+0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[1])+0.5, minor=False)

# want a more natural, table-like display
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.tick_top()

ax.set_xticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

What I am trying to get is something like this one:

[image]

Where I can see the color bar as well as value of the cells on them. What would I need to add to my code to get these?

Thanks

Comment: Somewhat relevant for the text on cells: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712047/matplotlib-imshow-matshow-display-values-on-plot/21712361#21712361

Comment: For the colorbar, have you tried `fig.colorbar(heatmap)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked into seaborn?

```
import seaborn as sns
data = np.random.rand(2,2)
sns.heatmap(data, annot=True,  linewidths=.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Haha yeah its a cool library: 
https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/

You can pass it a matplotlib axis as an arg and still use all your matplotlib functions like ax.set_xticks()
sns.heatmap(data, annot=True,  linewidths=.5, ax = ax)

Comment: how to run it in non-ipython environment?

Comment: oh got it. import matplotlib.pyplot as plt . plt.show()

Answer (score 5):

For the color bar, see [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html). You guessed correctly, the right function call is just [`ax.colorbar()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar).

Concerning the values on the `pcolor` plot, I'm afraid you have to add them "manually" using [`ax.text()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text). Calculate and loop over the cell center values and call the `text()` function. You can use the keyword arguments `horizontalalignment='center'` and `verticalalignment='center'` to keep the text value centered around `x, y`.