# Visualizing partial correlation

Tags: python, matplotlib

Following the answer from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/288273/partial-correlation-in-panda-dataframe-python

```
dict = {'x1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'x2': [2, 2, 3, 4, 2], 'x3': [10, 9, 5, 4, 9], 'y' : [5.077, 32.330, 65.140, 47.270, 80.570]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict, columns=['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'y'])
partial_corr_array = df.as_matrix()
np.round(partial_corr(partial_corr_array), decimals=2)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to get the visual output, which for me looks like so:

```
array([[ 1.  ,  0.52,  0.15,  0.91],
       [ 0.52,  1.  ,  0.25, -0.25],
       [ 0.15,  0.25,  1.  , -0.06],
       [ 0.91, -0.25, -0.06,  1.  ]])
```

identical to `df.corr().style.background_gradient()`? ie. heatmap with and annotations.

Note that this is a partial correlation, ie. we are controlling for the effect of the other variables.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "get the visual output".  All you've shown is printing the matrix.  We can't run your code, since you've neglected to include the critical function `partial_corr`.

Comment: @Prune Did you open the link? `def partial_corr(C)` is clearly stated in the answer

Comment: Please be aware there is a future warning on df.as_matrix().  You should fix this now before putting something into production that you might be too married to, to fix later.

Comment: @user8834780: no, I did not open the link.  Your question is supposed to be self-sufficient.  If the posted answer is what you're looking for, then that routine isn't part of the problem at all, and you're question should have hard-coded an example instead.  [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like the following:

**Figure 1**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
partial_corr_array = np.array([[ 1., 0.52, 0.15, 0.91], [ 0.52, 1., 0.25, -0.25], [ 0.15,  0.25,  1.  , -0.06], [ 0.91, -0.25, -0.06,  1.  ]])
plt.matshow(partial_corr_array)
plt.colorbar()
```

**Output**

[image]

**Figure 2** Based on [this](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/many_pairwise_correlations.html) link. Plotting only the lower half of the matrix because it is symmetric across the diagonal.

```
import seaborn as sns
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 5))
partial_corr_array = np.array([[ 1., 0.52, 0.15, 0.91], [ 0.52, 1., 0.25, -0.25], [ 0.15,  0.25,  1.  , -0.06], [ 0.91, -0.25, -0.06,  1.  ]])
mask = np.zeros_like(partial_corr_array, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(30, 10, as_cmap=True)
sns.heatmap(partial_corr_array, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmax=1, center=0,
            square=True, linewidths=1, cbar_kws={"shrink": 0.9}, annot=True)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Any way to add the measures you plot instead of the 0, 1, 2, 3? as well as annotate the actual correlation coefficient (not just use color scale)?

Comment: Edited my answer. For the first part (imshow) you can use something like given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712047/matplotlib-imshow-matshow-display-values-on-plot)

Answer (score 0):

[`seaborn.heatmap`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html#seaborn.heatmap) provides exactly this, use `fmt` to control the face value string format, and use `annot` to control whether the face value will be displayed (default False):

Additionally [`DataFrame.corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) gives a convenient method to calculate various types of correlation matrix, and returns a dataframe with column name and row names.  Seaborn by default will use those as axis trick labels.

```
In [28]: import seaborn as sns
In [39]: sns.heatmap(df.corr(), fmt='0.2f', annot=True)
Out[39]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xd961048>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer- but question is about partial correlation, not regular correlation